# Connection Reset by peer in AEM 6.1 publisher

Tags: maven, aem

I have done setup for AEM 6.1 for both author and publisher with Hotfixes and Service Packs specifed in documentation. Also deployed my project bundle into author. But while deploying same project into publisher I am getting this error.

Error:-

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.sling:maven-sling-plugin:2.0.6:install (install-bundle) on project Myproject-services: Installation on http://localhost:5503/apps/myproject/install failed, cause: Connection reset by peer: socket write error -> [Help 1]
```

pom.xml:-

```
<profile>
        <id>autoInstallBundlePublish</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <!-- Use the sling plugin to automatically deploy the bundle to the 
                    JCR tree -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-sling-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>install-bundle</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>install</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <slingUrl>http://localhost:5503</slingUrl>
                                <slingUrlSuffix>/apps/myproject/install</slingUrlSuffix>
                                <user>admin</user>
                                <password>admin</password>
                                <!-- <usePut>true</usePut>
                                <failOnError>true</failOnError> -->
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>

        </build>
    </profile>
```

Maven Command:-

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests=true -PautoInstallBundlePublish
```

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but it doesn't hurt to cover the basics. Does the folder /apps/myproject/install actually exist on the publish instance? And may I assume that you're running the publish on 5503 instead of the OOTB 4503?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default it uses the "WebConsole" method to deploy your package and therefore you need to point to *HOST:PORT/system/console* else you need to set the *deploymentMethod* configuration to "SlingPostServlet*.

For more details see the "install" goal documentation of the maven-sling-plugin:
https://sling.apache.org/documentation/development/sling.html

You need also to update to the latest maven-sling-plugin version 2.1.8.

Comment: Thanks for solution. After changing version of maven-sling-plugin and deploymentMethod configuration, its working now.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, please set the answer as "useful" so that it is clearly flagged.